# Magento 2 - PayPal Payments Pro changed

Tags: magento2, paypal-payments-pro

In my old Magento 1.7 store, the PayPal Payments Pro configuration asks for api username, api password, and api signature which I can easily get from my paypal account page. In Magento 2, it has changed and now I need partner, vendor, user, password fields instead. I've determined that this is for a PayFlow account but I can't figure out how to use my existing Payments Pro account. Why is it different than before? Do I need to sign up for PayFlow pro instead?

Comment: Yup you need to use Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) & Need to Signup As Well https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro?partner_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the Payment Pro solution is deprecated and uses Payflow as payment gateway, because this approach is required by PayPal https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/